# Skins issue on adding a telerik solution over server. System.InvalidOperationException: ..unable to find an embedded skin with the name 'WebBlue'

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dll, reference, telerik

I've just added a solution to a server and on adding the web part to the page get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Telerik.Web.UI.RadRating with ID='RadRating0' 
was unable to find an embedded skin with the name 'WebBlue'.
```

I have used Gacutil.exe to add the reference to Telerik.UI.dll and ..Skins.dll. Both are definitely copied over but in SharePoint LogViewer there still remains a problem with using the 'WebBlue' skin on the RadRatings.

Has anyone managed to solve this problem before? How do you carry over the skins added within the solution?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1. both Telerik.Web.UI and Telerik.Web.UI.Skins have the same version, to the letter
2. they are added as SafeControls in the SP web.config
3. the references in the project are OK (see this post on the matter: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-09-19/working-with-assemblies-in-the-global-assembly-cache).